# Type for array of subset of enum values (that warns if new enum member is not handled)

Tags: typescript

I have an enum:

```
enum Vehicles {
    CAR = 1,
    BOAT = 2,
    AIRPLANE = 3
}
```

and an array that contains a subset of that enum:

```
const vehiclesThatFly: VehiclesThatFly = [Vehicles.AIRPLANE]
```

How can I make a Typescript type, `VehiclesThatFly`, that will warn me when a new enum member is added to the enum so that I am forced to either 1) add that new member to my `vehiclesThatFly` array or 2. explicitly exclude it in the `VehiclesThatFly` type? In other words, if a new enum member is added, I do not want to have to remember to add it to `vehiclesThatFly`, I want TS to tell me that enum hasn't been handled.

I am imagining the `VehiclesThatFly` type would look something like this pseudocode: `Exclude<(Vehicles enum values), Vehicles.CAR | Vehicles.BOAT>`.

Is it possible to create a type like `VehiclesThatFly` or is there a better way to achieve my goal of having Typescript force me to explicitly handle new enum members?

Comment: unclear what you want, try to add minimal code example

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
type VehiclesSubset<T extends Record<Vehicles, boolean>> = {
  [K in keyof T]:
    T[K] extends true ? K : never
}[keyof T]
```

Here we have a generic type that accepts a type of vehicle/boolean pairs. It maps over these pairs, and if the value `T[K]` is `true` then uses that key `K` as the value, or if it is `false` then resolve to `never`. Then we index this mapped type by its own keys to get a union of the value types without the `never`s.

Which would be used like:

```
type VehiclesThatFly = VehiclesSubset<{
  [Vehicles.CAR]: false
  [Vehicles.BOAT]: false
  [Vehicles.AIRPLANE]: true
}>

const airplaneCanFly: VehiclesThatFly = Vehicles.AIRPLANE
const carCantFly: VehiclesThatFly = Vehicles.CAR // error
```

And this constraint here:

```
Record<Vehicles, boolean>
```

Requires an entry for each key of `Vehicles`. So if you add an enum entry, you should get type errors:

```
enum Vehicles {
    CAR = 1,
    BOAT = 2,
    AIRPLANE = 3,
    MOTORCYCLE = 4,
}

type VehiclesThatFly = VehiclesSubset<{
  [Vehicles.CAR]: false
  [Vehicles.BOAT]: false
  [Vehicles.AIRPLANE]: true
}>
// Type '{ 1: false; 2: false; 3: true; }' does not satisfy the constraint 'Record<Vehicles, boolean>'.
//  Property '4' is missing in type '{ 1: false; 2: false; 3: true; }' but required in type 'Record<Vehicles, boolean>'.(2344)
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/KYOwrgtgBAasAWBLAxgG2AZygbwLACgoioBhAQQCUoBeKARgBoDioAhAeTIBUaoAmJoWJkAkhQAKAGTIA5AKK8AzIJYB6VVACy7LuwokAmiUkLaAFgIBfAgQAuATwAOwWAhToMAZTAAjDMFsAHh5gAA9bUAATLApgZAB7ACdIwLgkNEwGKB94+PQAQxAAPiLePCEAbQBpKEQQKABrYHt4gDMoLgBdAC5mYi5qzqgwiJBoqFtEsBcAfiga7qgQYAA3YESrCqaW9q6bfAdnV3SPLnh82wAxVHteNPdMbz8AwPKiCvuMjAA6cgoeqCtfKofx9D5uL7fDjcAFAkHAMGfDzfUQSaTyAGTaZWIr7BIgDC2KD5RCJRyoQrAEiFa72RZIzBnC60u4Q5GoqSyOQEfGEqDIfKJakgK43elsxnnUW3WgMn5-KDqYaJRJJAhAA)